# Do configurations in containers always work on VMs or BareMetal Machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, ansible

I'm currently writing my master's thesis. I am testing infrastructure Code. For that the infrastructure is built with containers. I install Software and configure everything with Ansible. A key assumption of my work is that everything that works on containers will work on VMs or bare metal machines. Is there a scientific way to proof this or is there even a paper dealing with this topic?

Thanks in advance for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your key assumption : `... everything that works on containers will work on VMs or bare metal machines` is correct since container is just a specific sub-set of a VM or BareMetal OS.

Container uses the kernel of a VM/BareMetal but is more constraint in terms of resources and access to the host OS and it's hardware.

It will however not work vice-versa.

Further reading here: https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container